# My Azure Storage output blob never shows up

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-services, azure-functions

I'm trying to build a simple Azure Function that is based on the [ImageResizer example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-templates/tree/master/Templates/ImageResizer-CSharp), but uses the [Microsoft Cognitive Server Computer Vision API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api) to do the resize.

I have [working code for the Computer Vision API](https://github.com/martinkearn/Cognitive-Computer-Vision-Thumbnails-Sample) which I have ported into the Azure function.

It all seems to work ok (no errors) but my output blob never gets saved or shows up in the storage container. Not sure what I'm doing wrong as there are no errors to work with.

My CSX (C# function code) is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static void Run(Stream original, Stream thumb, TraceWriter log)
{
    //log.Verbose($"C# Blob trigger function processed: {myBlob}. Dimensions");
    string _apiKey = "PutYourComputerVisionApiKeyHere";
    string _apiUrlBase = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/generateThumbnail";
    string width = "100";
    string height = "100";
    bool smartcropping = true;

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        //setup HttpClient
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiUrlBase);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _apiKey);

        //setup data object
        HttpContent content = new StreamContent(original);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        // Request parameters
        var uri = $"{_apiUrlBase}?width={width}&height={height}&smartCropping={smartcropping}";

        //make request
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

        //log result
        log.Verbose($"Response: IsSucess={response.IsSuccessStatusCode}, Status={response.ReasonPhrase}");

        //read response and write to output stream
        thumb = new MemoryStream(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
    }
}
```

My function json is as follows

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "path": "originals/{name}",
      "connection": "thumbnailgenstorage_STORAGE",
      "name": "original",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "path": "thumbs/%rand-guid%",
      "connection": "thumbnailgenstorage_STORAGE",
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "thumb",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

My Azure storage account is called 'thumbnailgenstorage' and it has two containers named ['originals'](https://thumbnailgenstorage.blob.core.windows.net/originals) and ['thumbs'](https://thumbnailgenstorage.blob.core.windows.net/thumbs). The storage account key is `KGdcO+hjvARQvSwd2rfmdc+rrAsK0tA5xpE4RVNmXZgExCE+Cyk4q0nSiulDwvRHrSAkYjyjVezwdaeLCIb53g==`.

I'm perfectly happy for people to use my keys to help me figure this out! :)

Comment: I think I've fixed this. I'm not sure I was writing to eth output blob properly. This seems to work: '        //read response and write to output stream
        var responseBytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        thumb.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);'. Also, my output path in my json is now '"thumbs/%rand-guid%.jpg",'. Going to research a bit more and post a full answer when I'm confident it works

Comment: Yes that is correct - simple assignment to the Stream isn't the model, since it is not an 'out' parameter in the language sense. You have to write to the Stream provided. You'll find that to be the case across all the other bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working now. I was writing the output stream incorrectly.

This solution is an Azure function which triggers on the arrival of a blob in an Azure Blob Storage container called 'Originals', then uses the [Computer Vision API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api) to smartly resize the image and store in in a different blob container called 'Thumbs'.

Here is the working CSX (c# script):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static void Run(Stream original, Stream thumb, TraceWriter log)
{
    int width = 320;
    int height = 320;
    bool smartCropping = true;
    string _apiKey = "PutYourComputerVisionApiKeyHere";
    string _apiUrlBase = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/generateThumbnail";

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiUrlBase);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _apiKey);
        using (HttpContent content = new StreamContent(original))
        {
            //get response
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            var uri = $"{_apiUrlBase}?width={width}&height={height}&smartCropping={smartCropping.ToString()}";
            var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
            var responseBytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

            //write to output thumb
            thumb.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the integration JSON

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "path": "originals/{name}",
      "connection": "thumbnailgenstorage_STORAGE",
      "name": "original",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "path": "thumbs/{name}",
      "connection": "thumbnailgenstorage_STORAGE",
      "name": "thumb",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```